# PHP Warning: Division by zero error (temp tpl)

Tags: php

I am getting the following error:

`Warning: Division by zero in /home/vaibongd/public_html/temporary/%%B0^B0F^B0FD4939%%right2.tpl.php on line 19`

Line 19 is the first line in the code. I looked at some of the related questions and all my quote marks seem to be in the right place.

```
<?php if ($this->_tpl_vars['page'] == "" / vai / ""): ?>
            <div class="custom-block-content">
                <ul class="new_cungloai">
                    <?php unset($this->_sections['f']);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"" / vai / ""` here you divide by `""` which i guess is converting to an int (0).

Comment: can you pls suggest other ways ? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

your if condition will not work, because  `/ vai /` is not escaped.
Try this:

```
if ($this->_tpl_vars['page'] == '" / vai / "'):
```

or if you just want `/ vai /` use this:

```
if ($this->_tpl_vars['page'] == ' / vai / '):
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried but it doesn't work, this is a temporary tpl.php, I think maybe the problem is not this temp tpl?

Comment: I did, still not work, by the way, is it okay with the code in the original .tpl of this temp : {if $page eq ""/ vai /""}

Comment: var_dump($this->_tpl_vars['page']), I can't find it in the temp. I'm sorry. do you want to see the entire file of Right2.tpl and its temp right2.tp;.php?

Comment: I'm so sorry, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($this->_tpl_vars['page'] == "\" / vai / \""): // Just add slashes to ignore the quotes conflict
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried but it doesn't work, this is a temporary tpl.php, I think maybe the problem is not this temp tpl?